# how to output different two chart in jasperreport?

Tags: jasper-reports

i want to show 2 type charts,one's lineChart,another is stackedBarChart, there are two lists , the 1st for  lineChart,the 2st for stackedBarChart, i want show following:

lineChart (datasource:list1)

table1 (show list1 detail)

stackedBarChar t(datasource:list2)

table2 (show list2 detail)

thanks every one.

that 's my jrxml:

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="lineChartTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">

Answer (score 0):

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="lineChartTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">